How can I call a method in C++ internal DLL for a unity game
My goal is to call a function that gets the current visitor count, but I can't quite figure out how to do it with it not crashing the game. I'm okayish with c++ but am noob with reverse engineering and working with the stack.
Here is the function I'm looking to use:
"Signature": "int32_t User__get_VisitorsCount (User_o* __this, const MethodInfo* method);",
When I hook the function, and print the values, it works:
void Mods::HookGetShoppingVisitorsCount(void* thisPtr) {
    Utils::HookData& hook = hooks[1];

    // Unhook
    Unhook(hook.address, hook.originalBytes, 5);

    WriteToConsole("VisitorsCount getter accessed");

    
    uintptr_t ebpValue;
    uintptr_t valueAtEBPPlus8;

    __asm {
        mov ebpValue, ebp          // Capture the current EBP
        mov eax, [ebp + 0x8]       // Capture the value at EBP + 0x8
        mov valueAtEBPPlus8, eax   // Store it in valueAtEBPPlus8
    }

    // Log EBP
    WriteToConsole("EBP Value: %p", FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY, ebpValue);
    WriteToConsole("Value at [EBP + 0x8]: %p", FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY, valueAtEBPPlus8);


    // Capture the this pointer
    userPointer = static_cast<User*>(thisPtr);

    // Print the user pointer
    if (userPointer) {
        WriteToConsole("User pointer: %p", FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY, userPointer);
    } else {
        WriteToConsole("User pointer null", FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    }

    if (!originalShoppingVisitorsCount) {
        originalShoppingVisitorsCount = reinterpret_cast<int(*)(void*)>(hook.address);
    }

    // Call the original function
    int visitorsCount = originalShoppingVisitorsCount(thisPtr);

    // Log the visitor count
    WriteToConsole("Shopping Visitors Count: %d", FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY, visitorsCount);

    // Re-hook
   // Hook(hook.address, (void*)(&Mods::HookGetShoppingVisitorsCount), 5, hook.originalBytes);
}

This value returns:
ShoppingVisitorsCount getter accessed! at [2024-09-09 04:53:52]
EBP Value: 00F2E7DC at [2024-09-09 04:53:52]
Value at [EBP + 0x8]: 48C40AA0 at [2024-09-09 04:53:52]
User pointer captured: 48C40AA0 at [2024-09-09 04:53:52]
Visitors Count: 2 at [2024-09-09 04:53:52]

but when calling it the function, it crashes the game
Calling code:
void Hacks::CallUserFunction() {
    if (userPointer) {
   
        WriteToConsole("Gold: %ld", FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY, userPointer->gold->_value);
        WriteToConsole("Gems: %ld", FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY, userPointer->gems->_value);
        WriteToConsole("Coins: %ld", FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY, userPointer->coins->_value);
        WriteToConsole("XP: %ld", FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY, userPointer->xp->_value);

        // Get the base addy of dll
        uintptr_t baseAddress = BaseAddy;
        if (!baseAddress) {
            WriteToConsole("Failed to get base address!", FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
            return;
        }

        // base address
        WriteToConsole("Base Address: %p", FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY, baseAddress);

        // real address of the VisitorsCount function
        uintptr_t realAddress = baseAddress + 0xC810E0;

        // MethodInfo pointer
        uintptr_t methodInfoAddress = baseAddress + 0x263CCA8;

        // Read the MethodInfo pointer
        const void* methodInfo = nullptr;
        try {
            methodInfo = *reinterpret_cast<void**>(methodInfoAddress);  // Deref
            if (!methodInfo) {
                WriteToConsole("MethodInfo pointer null", FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
                return;
            }
        } catch (...) {
            WriteToConsole("Exception while dereferencing MethodInfo!", FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
            return;
        }

        // Log MethodInfo addresses
        WriteToConsole("Real Address: %p", FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY, realAddress);
        WriteToConsole("MethodInfo Address: %p", FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY, methodInfo);

        
        typedef int32_t(__thiscall* ShoppingVisitorsCountFunc)(User* user, const void* methodInfo);

        
        ShoppingVisitorsCountFunc GetShoppingVisitorsCount = reinterpret_cast<ShoppingVisitorsCountFunc>(realAddress);


        WriteToConsole("User Pointer: %p", FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY, userPointer);


        if (!GetShoppingVisitorsCount) {
            WriteToConsole("Function pointer is null!", FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
            return;
        }

        // Log all
        std::ofstream logFile(R"(C:\Users\****\Documents\Code\log.txt)", std::ios::app);  // Append mode
        if (logFile.is_open()) {
            logFile << std::hex << std::uppercase;  // Set output to hexadecimal and uppercase
            logFile << "User Pointer: 0x" << (uintptr_t)userPointer << "\n";
            logFile << "Base Address: 0x" << (uintptr_t)baseAddress << "\n";
            logFile << "Real Address: 0x" << (uintptr_t)realAddress << "\n";
            logFile << "MethodInfo Address: 0x" << (uintptr_t)methodInfoAddress << "\n";
            logFile.close();  // Close the file after writing
        } else {
            WriteToConsole("Failed to open log file!", FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
        }

        // Call the function
try {
    int visitorsCount = GetShoppingVisitorsCount(userPointer, methodInfo);


    WriteToConsole("Visitors Count: %d", FOREGROUND_GREEN | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY, visitorsCount);
} catch (...) {
    WriteToConsole("Exceptionwhile calling GetShoppingVisitorsCount", FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
}

    } else {
        WriteToConsole("User pointer null", FOREGROUND_RED | FOREGROUND_INTENSITY);
    }
}

this is the stack of the function:
il2cpp:5E0B10E0 sub_5E0B10E0    proc near               ; CODE XREF: sub_5D7D07E0+C3↑p
il2cpp:5E0B10E0                                         ; sub_5D7D16C0+C3↑p ...
il2cpp:5E0B10E0
il2cpp:5E0B10E0 var_30          = dword ptr -30h
il2cpp:5E0B10E0 var_2C          = dword ptr -2Ch
il2cpp:5E0B10E0 var_28          = dword ptr -28h
il2cpp:5E0B10E0 var_24          = dword ptr -24h
il2cpp:5E0B10E0 var_20          = dword ptr -20h
il2cpp:5E0B10E0 var_1C          = dword ptr -1Ch
il2cpp:5E0B10E0 var_18          = dword ptr -18h
il2cpp:5E0B10E0 var_14          = dword ptr -14h
il2cpp:5E0B10E0 var_10          = dword ptr -10h
il2cpp:5E0B10E0 var_C           = dword ptr -0Ch
il2cpp:5E0B10E0 var_4           = dword ptr -4
il2cpp:5E0B10E0 arg_0           = dword ptr  8
il2cpp:5E0B10E0
il2cpp:5E0B10E0                 push    ebp
il2cpp:5E0B10E1                 mov     ebp, esp
il2cpp:5E0B10E3                 push    0FFFFFFFFh
il2cpp:5E0B10E5                 push    offset SEH_10C810E0
il2cpp:5E0B10EA                 mov     eax, large fs:0
il2cpp:5E0B10F0                 push    eax
il2cpp:5E0B10F1                 mov     large fs:0, esp
il2cpp:5E0B10F8                 sub     esp, 24h
il2cpp:5E0B10FB                 cmp     byte_6033548E, 0
il2cpp:5E0B1102                 push    ebx
il2cpp:5E0B1103                 push    esi
il2cpp:5E0B1104                 push    edi
il2cpp:5E0B1105                 mov     [ebp+var_10], esp
il2cpp:5E0B1108                 jnz     short loc_5E0B1146
il2cpp:5E0B110A                 push    offset dword_6026D180
il2cpp:5E0B110F                 call    sub_5D650490
il2cpp:5E0B1114                 push    offset dword_60232A1C
il2cpp:5E0B1119                 call    sub_5D650490
il2cpp:5E0B111E                 push    offset dword_6023A3E0
il2cpp:5E0B1123                 call    sub_5D650490
il2cpp:5E0B1128                 push    offset dword_6026DFC4
il2cpp:5E0B112D                 call    sub_5D650490
il2cpp:5E0B1132                 push    offset dword_60260B1C
il2cpp:5E0B1137                 call    sub_5D650490
il2cpp:5E0B113C                 add     esp, 14h
il2cpp:5E0B113F                 mov     byte_6033548E, 1
il2cpp:5E0B1146
il2cpp:5E0B1146 loc_5E0B1146:                           ; CODE XREF: sub_5E0B10E0+28↑j
il2cpp:5E0B1146                 mov     eax, [ebp+arg_0]
il2cpp:5E0B1149                 xor     edi, edi
il2cpp:5E0B114B                 mov     [ebp+var_14], 0
il2cpp:5E0B1152                 mov     [ebp+var_18], edi
il2cpp:5E0B1155                 mov     eax, [eax+134h]
il2cpp:5E0B115B                 test    eax, eax
il2cpp:5E0B115D                 jz      loc_5E0B12CD
il2cpp:5E0B1163                 push    dword_60260B1C
il2cpp:5E0B1169                 push    eax
il2cpp:5E0B116A                 call    sub_5EDBA970
il2cpp:5E0B116F                 add     esp, 8
il2cpp:5E0B1172                 test    eax, eax
il2cpp:5E0B1174                 jz      loc_5E0B12CD
il2cpp:5E0B117A                 push    eax
il2cpp:5E0B117B                 push    dword_60232A1C
il2cpp:5E0B1181                 push    edi
il2cpp:5E0B1182                 call    sub_5D4328F0
il2cpp:5E0B1187                 add     esp, 0Ch
il2cpp:5E0B118A                 mov     [ebp+var_14], eax
il2cpp:5E0B118D                 xor     ebx, ebx
il2cpp:5E0B118F                 lea     esi, [ebp+var_14]
il2cpp:5E0B1192                 mov     [ebp+var_30], ebx
il2cpp:5E0B1195                 mov     [ebp+var_2C], esi
il2cpp:5E0B1198                 mov     [ebp+var_4], ebx
il2cpp:5E0B119B                 mov     byte ptr [ebp+var_4], 1
il2cpp:5E0B119F                 nop
il2cpp:5E0B11A0
il2cpp:5E0B11A0 loc_5E0B11A0:                           ; CODE XREF: sub_5E0B10E0+15F↓j
il2cpp:5E0B11A0                                         ; sub_5E0B10E0+167↓j ...
il2cpp:5E0B11A0                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_14]
il2cpp:5E0B11A3                 test    eax, eax
il2cpp:5E0B11A5                 jz      loc_5E0B12CD
il2cpp:5E0B11AB                 push    eax
il2cpp:5E0B11AC                 push    dword_6026DFC4
il2cpp:5E0B11B2                 push    0
il2cpp:5E0B11B4                 call    sub_5D4328F0
il2cpp:5E0B11B9                 add     esp, 0Ch
il2cpp:5E0B11BC                 test    al, al
il2cpp:5E0B11BE                 jz      loc_5E0B1267
il2cpp:5E0B11C4                 mov     ebx, [ebp+var_14]
il2cpp:5E0B11C7                 mov     [ebp+var_20], ebx
il2cpp:5E0B11CA                 test    ebx, ebx
il2cpp:5E0B11CC                 jz      loc_5E0B12CD
il2cpp:5E0B11D2                 mov     ecx, [ebx]
il2cpp:5E0B11D4                 xor     eax, eax
il2cpp:5E0B11D6                 mov     [ebp+var_1C], ecx
il2cpp:5E0B11D9                 mov     [ebp+arg_0], eax
il2cpp:5E0B11DC                 movzx   edx, word ptr [ecx+0B6h]
il2cpp:5E0B11E3                 mov     [ebp+var_24], edx
il2cpp:5E0B11E6                 cmp     ax, dx
il2cpp:5E0B11E9                 jnb     short loc_5E0B1213
il2cpp:5E0B11EB                 nop     dword ptr [eax+eax+00h]
il2cpp:5E0B11F0
il2cpp:5E0B11F0 loc_5E0B11F0:                           ; CODE XREF: sub_5E0B10E0+131↓j
il2cpp:5E0B11F0                 mov     edx, [ebp+var_1C]
il2cpp:5E0B11F3                 mov     ebx, dword_6023A3E0
il2cpp:5E0B11F9                 movzx   ecx, ax
il2cpp:5E0B11FC                 mov     esi, [edx+58h]
il2cpp:5E0B11FF                 mov     edx, [ebp+var_24]
il2cpp:5E0B1202                 cmp     [esi+ecx*8], ebx
il2cpp:5E0B1205                 lea     esi, [ebp+var_14]
il2cpp:5E0B1208                 mov     ebx, [ebp+var_20]
il2cpp:5E0B120B                 jz      short loc_5E0B1256
il2cpp:5E0B120D                 inc     eax
il2cpp:5E0B120E                 cmp     ax, dx
il2cpp:5E0B1211                 jb      short loc_5E0B11F0
il2cpp:5E0B1213
il2cpp:5E0B1213 loc_5E0B1213:                           ; CODE XREF: sub_5E0B10E0+109↑j
il2cpp:5E0B1213                 push    0
il2cpp:5E0B1215                 push    dword_6023A3E0
il2cpp:5E0B121B                 push    ebx
il2cpp:5E0B121C                 call    sub_5D5DC9E0
il2cpp:5E0B1221                 add     esp, 0Ch
il2cpp:5E0B1224                 mov     ecx, eax
il2cpp:5E0B1226
il2cpp:5E0B1226 loc_5E0B1226:                           ; CODE XREF: sub_5E0B10E0+185↓j
il2cpp:5E0B1226                 push    dword ptr [ecx+4]
il2cpp:5E0B1229                 mov     eax, [ecx]
il2cpp:5E0B122B                 push    ebx
il2cpp:5E0B122C                 call    eax
il2cpp:5E0B122E                 add     esp, 8
il2cpp:5E0B1231                 test    eax, eax
il2cpp:5E0B1233                 jz      loc_5E0B12CD
il2cpp:5E0B1239                 mov     eax, [eax+28h]
il2cpp:5E0B123C                 cmp     eax, 4
il2cpp:5E0B123F                 jz      loc_5E0B11A0
il2cpp:5E0B1245                 test    eax, eax
il2cpp:5E0B1247                 jz      loc_5E0B11A0
il2cpp:5E0B124D                 inc     edi
il2cpp:5E0B124E                 mov     [ebp+var_18], edi
il2cpp:5E0B1251                 jmp     loc_5E0B11A0
il2cpp:5E0B1256 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
il2cpp:5E0B1256
il2cpp:5E0B1256 loc_5E0B1256:                           ; CODE XREF: sub_5E0B10E0+12B↑j
il2cpp:5E0B1256                 mov     edx, [ebx]
il2cpp:5E0B1258                 mov     eax, [edx+58h]
il2cpp:5E0B125B                 mov     ecx, [eax+ecx*8+4]
il2cpp:5E0B125F                 add     ecx, 18h
il2cpp:5E0B1262                 lea     ecx, [edx+ecx*8]
il2cpp:5E0B1265                 jmp     short loc_5E0B1226
il2cpp:5E0B1267 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
il2cpp:5E0B1267
il2cpp:5E0B1267 loc_5E0B1267:                           ; CODE XREF: sub_5E0B10E0+DE↑j
il2cpp:5E0B1267                 mov     [ebp+var_4], 0FFFFFFFFh
il2cpp:5E0B126E                 mov     eax, [esi]
il2cpp:5E0B1270                 test    eax, eax
il2cpp:5E0B1272                 jz      short loc_5E0B1285
il2cpp:5E0B1274                 push    eax
il2cpp:5E0B1275                 push    dword_6026D180
il2cpp:5E0B127B                 push    0
il2cpp:5E0B127D                 call    sub_5D432A20
il2cpp:5E0B1282                 add     esp, 0Ch
il2cpp:5E0B1285
il2cpp:5E0B1285 loc_5E0B1285:                           ; CODE XREF: sub_5E0B10E0+192↑j
il2cpp:5E0B1285                 xor     ebx, ebx
il2cpp:5E0B1287                 mov     eax, edi
il2cpp:5E0B1289                 mov     ecx, [ebp+var_C]
il2cpp:5E0B128C                 mov     large fs:0, ecx
il2cpp:5E0B1293                 pop     edi
il2cpp:5E0B1294                 pop     esi
il2cpp:5E0B1295                 pop     ebx
il2cpp:5E0B1296                 mov     esp, ebp
il2cpp:5E0B1298                 pop     ebp
il2cpp:5E0B1299                 retn
il2cpp:5E0B129A ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
il2cpp:5E0B129A
il2cpp:5E0B129A loc_5E0B129A:                           ; DATA XREF: .rdata:stru_600DD290↓o
il2cpp:5E0B129A                 mov     eax, [ebp+var_28]
il2cpp:5E0B129D                 mov     eax, [eax]
il2cpp:5E0B129F                 mov     [ebp+var_30], eax
il2cpp:5E0B12A2                 mov     eax, offset loc_5E0B12A8
il2cpp:5E0B12A7                 retn
il2cpp:5E0B12A8 ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
il2cpp:5E0B12A8
il2cpp:5E0B12A8 loc_5E0B12A8:                           ; CODE XREF: sub_5E0B10E0+1C7↑j
il2cpp:5E0B12A8                                         ; DATA XREF: sub_5E0B10E0+1C2↑o
il2cpp:5E0B12A8                 lea     ecx, [ebp+var_30]
il2cpp:5E0B12AB                 mov     [ebp+var_4], 0FFFFFFFFh
il2cpp:5E0B12B2                 call    sub_5D4326B0
il2cpp:5E0B12B7                 mov     edi, [ebp+var_18]
il2cpp:5E0B12BA                 mov     ecx, [ebp+var_C]
il2cpp:5E0B12BD                 mov     eax, edi
il2cpp:5E0B12BF                 pop     edi
il2cpp:5E0B12C0                 pop     esi
il2cpp:5E0B12C1                 mov     large fs:0, ecx
il2cpp:5E0B12C8                 pop     ebx
il2cpp:5E0B12C9                 mov     esp, ebp
il2cpp:5E0B12CB                 pop     ebp
il2cpp:5E0B12CC                 retn
il2cpp:5E0B12CD ; ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
il2cpp:5E0B12CD
il2cpp:5E0B12CD loc_5E0B12CD:                           ; CODE XREF: sub_5E0B10E0+7D↑j
il2cpp:5E0B12CD                                         ; sub_5E0B10E0+94↑j ...
il2cpp:5E0B12CD                 call    sub_5D6506A0
il2cpp:5E0B12CD sub_5E0B10E0    endp

Am I just too noobish to figure out where to find the methodInfo*? Is it a Call Convention issue? All input is useful to my lil journey, thank you all in advance
I went through multiple calling conventions, tried each of the addresses pushed onto stack as references for MethodInfo*, I'm just a little lost for this part

Here is an example of using extern c wrapper within unity: https://github.com/CodingConnected/CodingConnected.Traci/tree/master/CodingConnected.TraCI.C

Thank you for the detailed question and an interesting puzzle. It is not clear to me where it crashes or with what exception. Knowing the framework you are using is helpful as well. il2cpp:5E0B10E0 (this is the original GetShoppingVisitorsCount function?) seems cut off at the end after calling sub_5D6506A0.
Regardless, in Hacks::CallUserFunction() you are calling typedef int32_t(__thiscall* ShoppingVisitorsCountFunc)(User* user, const void* methodInfo);
The current Hacks object pointer is then the this pointer of il2cpp:5E0B10E0. But I suspect that the called function is expecting the Mods object as this (if it's a __thiscall) and that may very well be the source of the crash.
I also think that il2cpp:5E0B10E0 is NOT __thiscall and it only has one argument, as ECS does not seem to be used (other than passibly in one of the sub-functions. It also seems to endlessly recurse if the DWORD at arg0 + 0x134 is null.
Reference: visual studio this calling convention: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/thiscall?view=msvc-170
